# Flask curl -d dont print in the console on windows

Tags: python, flask, curl

I'm starting learn Flask and i testing the http request for the console, and when i try to print a form.request on flask using the curl -d and print it on the code, the console is not printing the form request

[image]

(here is where is expected to print this and is not printing it

[image]

and heres the code

[image]

Like the code print it just 1 time, but when i execute the lele() again is not printing anymore

[image]

just when i add that line, no when i call lele()

Idk if is a windows thing, because i do this on Mac and it works, so idk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from flask import Flask,request
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/lele",methods=["GET","POST"])
def lele():
    """ You can test this in postman by selecting `form-data` in the
    `Body` and giving the `name` as key and value michael (let's say)."""
    user=request.form['name'] 
    return str(user) # this is a POST request
    # return "lele"  # this is a GET request

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

- request.form: It is the dictionary object which contains the key-value pair of form parameters and their values.

when you run `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/lele` the function should return `lele` and that is what is being returned. If you want to see `lele` as an output,then it is a GET request. If you want to see `michael` as an output,then it is a POST request.